# Editing a executables files details

Tags: c#, windows

I have a (crap) netbook that is given to all students in NSW, Australia in year 9. The thing is you cannot run executables other then the ones installed on the system due to a group policy. I have writen a program in java (and got [eclipse working on it](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/134738/java-ide-written-in-pure-java)) that searches directories in C:\Windows and C:\Program Files that are writable. No locations are writable in C:\Windows, but in C:\Program Files there is a location which contains multiple executables which you can read/write. So I backed these up, then copied over Firefox portable (since we are stuck with ie7) and renamed the executable name to the one I backed up, but still can't run it. So now, I am assuming (and also checked in the registry) that when you run a program it is checked against a white-list, it not only checks the executable name and folder, but the files details (file description, copyright info, etc). So, I was wondering if it is possible to edit these file attributes by writting a program? And could anyone please provide me with source code examples on how I would do this, preferably in C#.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You're sure the file details (description, copyright, title) are checked? And are you sure this is from a group policy? This sounds pretty interesting.

Comment: Um... 80% sure... And it is definatly caused by group policy.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just place the portable version of an app in your user folders, which would definitely be writeable? Chrome even installs this way by default.

Comment: Btw, take a look at the different methods: http://www.windows7library.com/blog/security/how-to-restrict-applications-using-group-policies/. If the group policy says, "restrict everything but allow only these hashed programs to run", you're screwed. You wouldn't happen to be...an administrator right?

Comment: @Jason I get the following error: "This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator." No I am not a system admin :D

Comment: @Cody Gray All programs which are not installed as a default on the system are blocked.

Comment: And I cannot acsess group policy editor :)

Comment: Yes, I see that now. Then your only choice is to "hack" it. That shouldn't be too hard: as I'm fond of saying, when you have physical access to the hardware, no security mechanism is relevant. Group policies are easy enough to get around when you hold the laptop in your hand (and maybe a Windows CD). I'm not sure that such topics are considered on-topic here, and I'm not really sure that your school would appreciate me telling you how to bypass their security measures, though.

Comment: Well, um... Actually it is the government's security measures :D But naturally, I would appreciate it :)

Comment: If you're not afraid of most likely violating your contract, download this (http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/), boot from the CD, make your user account an Administrator, boot up, login, create a new Administrator account, use that, delete it at the end of the year when you return the laptop. Seriously the most practical (apart from violating your contract) instead of dodging registry hacks. Or if you have enough disk space, install Windows to another partition, and delete that partition at the end of the year - completely worry-free. Nobody will ever find out.

Comment: Well, The thing is they check the laptops every year, and everything is logged (apparently). But, in previous years no one got introuble for runing exe's. I have tryed there, special directory that are now readonly. And I *am* afraid of violating the contract.

Comment: So, if you have enough disk space, create a completely separate partition and install Windows to that new partition. Your old Windows won't even be running, so there's no possibility of logging your activity. Just remember to remove that partition at the end of the year. This would probably make your computer even faster and cleaner.

Comment: Mmmm. I guess I could, altough there is no optical drive so i'll have to "borrow" (hehe) my dad's usb and put the Windows 7 installation stuff on there. But, still, I guess if the computing teacher sees me she will be like, "Why are you an admin".

Comment: Err, ok. Ask a friend for an Ubuntu CD. You can run Ubuntu from a CD without installing anything - so you are literally not even using your harddisk (you could disconnect it). Or you could buy a cheap 4 GB USB and install Ubuntu to that, so that you can actually install programs and save data. Not a bad choice really. Absolutely no possibility of logging. JK your teacher sees this. Just sit in the back of the class.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8751/discussion-between-jason-and-darestium)

Comment: @Jason Good sir, I have finally found a way to run executables and thought you might be interested in the answer. I found this Java application that someone wrote that kills the running version of windows explorer and starts it's own version :), I have yet to decompile the program an figure out how it works, but it works like a charm. If your interested here it is: http://www.mediafire.com/?sf4t1iv1l4wbf68

Comment: Haha wow, you've still been on this for 2 months. Glad to hear you finally got something working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Java application that kills explorer then starts it own version (assuming without polices applied) http://www.mediafire.com/?sf4t1iv1l4wbf68